# Can I have different sessions with different servers for the same service?

Tags: browser, ip, domain, session, mail-server

As already known that one domain can have multiple IPs with multiple servers. So if I open for example my Yahoo account, then I'll have a session with one of Yahoo servers.

My question: if like after a few minutes I open a new window and go for my Yahoo account, is it possible that I'll have another session with another Yahoo server (while the first connection is kept). Or I'll *always be connected to the same server* as long as I'm logged in.

Comment: Are you closing the original window?

Comment: @Burgi no, I keep it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log into a web service like Yahoo the web server passes a tiny text file to your computer called a cookie. This cookie will contain a single string of information, usually a randomly generated authentication key from the server. The web server will also specify a time when that cookie is no longer valid.

If you open a new window and again access a Yahoo service the software running on the server will check if you already have an authentication key and that the key matches the one it has in the database for your session.

Cookies are browser specific which means if you have more than one browser on your pc (Chrome and IE for example) you can actually log in multiple times. This is the same as running the browser in privacy mode, all the cookies associated with account log in will be removed once the final privacy window has been closed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know this cookie thing already. But what I need to know is whether I can open my account with different servers at the same time or it will always be with the same server

Comment: All the servers for a service like Yahoo act like a single server, they share the login information amongst themselves so it doesn't matter which individual server you connect to the result is the same.